# Can you change time zones on calendars?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar

I have a site that contains nine calendars for events happening in various time zones. Is it possible to set the time zone for each calendar? How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: This setting is available at site level and not with Calendar.

Comment: Seems like the only out-of-the-box solution is to make a sub site for each calendar then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change regional settings on a site-by-site basis and this is not available at list(Calendar) level. A site collection can consist of a top-level site and one or more subsites. The regional settings for the top-level site of a site collection are automatically set based on the default language of the site collection. When you create a subsite, the subsite inherits the regional settings of the parent site. If you are a site owner, then you can specify different regional settings.

**To change the regional settings for a SharePoint site**

1. Open the site on which you want to change the regional settings.
2. On the Site Actions menu, choose Site Settings.
3. On the Site Settings page, under Site Administration, choose Regional settings.
4. On the Regional Settings page, select the settings that you want for this site, and then choose the OK button.